# Row in HTML wont fill full screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a products page on my current website test and I have found that the "Row" in my HTML code wont fill the fullscreen preventing me from centering the contents or even bringing the cards underneath to the same row as the first 3.

```js
let products = {
  data: [{
      productName: "Regular White T-Shirt",
      category: "Topwear",
      price: "30",
      image: "images/products/white-tshirt.jpg",
    },
    {
      productName: "Beige Short Skirt",
      category: "Bottomwear",
      price: "49",
      image: "images/products/short-skirt.jpg",
    },
    {
      productName: "Sporty SmartWatch",
      category: "Watch",
      price: "99",
      image: "images/products/sporty-smartwatch.jpg",
    },
    {
      productName: "Basic Knitted Top",
      category: "Topwear",
      price: "29",
      image: "images/products/knitted-top.jpg",
    },
    {
      productName: "Black Leather Jacket",
      category: "Jacket",
      price: "129",
      image: "images/products/black-leather-jacket.jpg",
    },
    {
      productName: "Stylish Pink Trousers",
      category: "Bottomwear",
      price: "89",
      image: "images/products/pink-trousers.jpg",
    },
    {
      productName: "Brown Men's Jacket",
      category: "Jacket",
      price: "189",
      image: "images/products/brown-jacket.jpg",
    },
    {
      productName: "Comfy Gray Pants",
      category: "Bottomwear",
      price: "49",
      image: "images/products/comfy-gray-pants.jpg",
    },
  ],
};

for (let i of products.data) {
  //Create Card
  let card = document.createElement("div");
  //Card should have category and should stay hidden initially
  card.classList.add("card", i.category, "hide");
  //image div
  let imgContainer = document.createElement("div");
  imgContainer.classList.add("image-container");
  //img tag
  let image = document.createElement("img");
  image.setAttribute("src", i.image);
  imgContainer.appendChild(image);
  card.appendChild(imgContainer);
  //container
  let container = document.createElement("div");
  container.classList.add("container");
  //product name
  let name = document.createElement("h5");
  name.classList.add("product-name");
  name.innerText = i.productName.toUpperCase();
  container.appendChild(name);
  //price
  let price = document.createElement("h6");
  price.innerText = "$" + i.price;
  container.appendChild(price);
  card.appendChild(container);
  document.getElementById("products").appendChild(card);
}
//parameter passed from button (Parameter same as category)
function filterProduct(value) {
  //Button class code
  let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".button-value");
  buttons.forEach((button) => {
    //check if value equals innerText
    if (value.toUpperCase() == button.innerText.toUpperCase()) {
      button.classList.add("active");
    } else {
      button.classList.remove("active");
    }
  });
  //select all cards
  let elements = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
  //loop through all cards
  elements.forEach((element) => {
    //display all cards on 'all' button click
    if (value == "all") {
      element.classList.remove("hide");
    } else {
      //Check if element contains category class
      if (element.classList.contains(value)) {
        //display element based on category
        element.classList.remove("hide");
      } else {
        //hide other elements
        element.classList.add("hide");
      }
    }
  });
}
//Search button click
document.getElementById("search").addEventListener("click", () => {
  //initializations
  let searchInput = document.getElementById("search-input").value;
  let elements = document.querySelectorAll(".product-name");
  let cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
  //loop through all elements
  elements.forEach((element, index) => {
    //check if text includes the search value
    if (element.innerText.includes(searchInput.toUpperCase())) {
      //display matching card
      cards[index].classList.remove("hide");
    } else {
      //hide others
      cards[index].classList.add("hide");
    }
  });
});
//Initially display all products
window.onload = () => {
  filterProduct("all");
};
```

```css
nav#navbar {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
}

nav#navbar ul.navbar-nav {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: LIGHTBLUE;
  font-size: 75px;
}

.centered2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 78%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#search-container {
  margin: 1em 0;
}

#search-container input {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 40%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #110f29;
  padding: 1em 0.3em;
}

#search-container input:focus {
  border-bottom-color: #6759ff;
}

#search-container button {
  padding: 1em 2em;
  margin-left: 1em;
  background-color: #6759ff;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

.button-value {
  border: 2px solid #6759ff;
  padding: 1em 2.2em;
  border-radius: 3em;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #6759ff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#products {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-column-gap: 1.5em;
  padding: 2em 0;
}

.card {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  max-width: 18em;
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1em 2em 2.5em rgba(1, 2, 68, 0.08);
}

.image-container {
  text-align: center;
}

img[src^="images/products/"] {
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  height: 15em;
}

.container {
  padding-top: 1em;
  color: #110f29;
}

.container h5 {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  .card {
    max-width: 10em;
    margin-top: 1em;
  }
  #products {
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    grid-column-gap: 1em;
  }
}

.col-md-12#footer {
  background-color: rgb(37, 37, 37) !important;
  height: 5em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  padding-left: 0;
  bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Bootstrap test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/products.css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bangers' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display&family=Quicksand&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="JavaScript/products.js" defer></script>
</head>


<body>
  <!--Navigation bar-->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark navbar-fixed-top transparent sticky-top" id="navbar">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
      <img src="images/DallE_Extendo-removebg.png" width="80" height="60" alt="">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="aboutus.html">About us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="products.html">Products</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="contactus.html">Contact us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!--NavBar Ends-->


  <!--Content Begins-->
  <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); padding-bottom: 100px; padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0;">
    <img src="images/TEST.jpg" id="TitleImg" style="width: 100%; max-height: 533px; padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0;">
    <div class="centered">Products</div>
    <div class="centered2">All products are avaliable to purchase in the shop</div>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div id="search-container">
            <input type="search" id="search-input" placeholder="Search product name here.." />
            <button id="search">Search</button>
          </div>
          <div id="buttons">
            <button class="button-value" onclick="filterProduct('all')">All</button>
            <button class="button-value" onclick="filterProduct('Topwear')">Topwear</button>
            <button class="button-value" onclick="filterProduct('Bottomwear')">Bottomwear</button>
            <button class="button-value" onclick="filterProduct('Jacket')">Jacket</button>
            <button class="button-value" onclick="filterProduct('Watch')">Watch</button>
          </div>
          <div id="products"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12" id="footer">
          <div class="col-md-1" style="font-size: 10px;">
            <p>TEST</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4" id="addy" style="padding-left: 1%; text-align: center;">
            <p style="white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; "></p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4" id="sm" style="padding-left: 10%; padding-bottom: 1%; display: flex;">
            </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3" style="text-align: center; padding-left: 0;">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I just hit a block on this and can't seem to get by it.

Comment: please provide your code as [repro] and while you do, pay extra attention to the word **minimal**. 450 lines of code are excessive and most likely not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer to your question: the row will adapt it's width according to the elements inside.
Your "wrapper" which is exactly after the row should have a property of `width: 100%;` if you wish. That way it will fill the whole page.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Give "width: 100%" in wrapper class and try.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).